# Drawing online simultaneously on the iPad

Tags: ipad, web-applications, simultaneous

Is there a Webapp or App for the iPad that enables two users to draw simultaneously on a canvas such that user B can watch in real time what user A is drawing in vice versa.

I mean, is there something similar for the iPad as for example can be found at [FlockDraw](http://flockdraw.com/) (which is unfortunatly a flash app)

Having such a tool would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Snibbe just released an [app](http://www.snibbestudio.com/2012/01/26/motionphone/) which does something of that sort. I'm sure there are other examples out there. Search for *shared whiteboard app*

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. Technology is so awesome... I love it!!!